# How to use a variable with multiple values as a parameter in the where clause sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to create a "where clause" that can handle multi-valued parameter but not getting it to work.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product]
(
    [ProductKey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Productnr] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [Color] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
) 

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Product] ([Productnr], [Color])  
VALUES ('45678', 'Red'),
       ('98765', 'Blue'),
       ('46547', 'Black')
```

With the above sample table I wish to create a query that filters the rows with colors red and blue using a variable parameter like the following:

```
DECLARE @Color varchar(50) = 'Red,Blue';

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Product] 
WHERE [Color] IN (@Color)
```

I tried using the `STRING_SPLIT` function but didn't get it to work (result output is empty)

```
DECLARE @Color varchar(50) = 'Red,Blue';

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Product] 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Color, ',') 
              WHERE [Color] IN (SELECT @Color 
                                FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Color, ',')))
```

If remove the Blue from the Variable and only pass "Red" it works create but not when I try to pass multiple values.

Comment: Please don't put SQL in HTML snippets... SQL *isn't* HTML; they are completely different languages. If you want to provide a runnable example as well, then use a fiddle website (such as [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk)).

Comment: What about a table valued parameter, which is how it is supposed to be done? How are you calling this code, what is your client application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IN`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM [dbo].[Product] p 
WHERE p.Color IN (SELECT s.value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Color, ',') s)
```

Comment: Sorry mate I didn't see who was first, I changed to you if you were first.

Comment: I wish there was a way to accept multiple solutions/answers

Answer (score 1):

Only some part changed inside exists condition:

```
DECLARE @Color varchar(50) = 'Red,Blue';

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Product] 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Color, ',') A 
              WHERE a.[value] = product.color)
```